# Disposing assets and Screens in libgdx

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, libgdx, dispose

I programmed a game made of multiple screens and every time I need a new screen I use the code

```
dispose();
game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
```

Inside the dispose method I called the dispose method of each asset like Textures and so on.
I also use the asset manager to load the assets required for the game play screen. In that case when I close the game play screen I also call `AssetManager.clear()`.

Now when I start the game I only have the menu screen and the used memory is about 20MB, then in the game play screen I reach 212MB and when I come back to the menu screen, after disposing the AssetManger, I still have 186MB.
The main problem is that if I start a new game play screen the memory reaches 320MB so after some game play screens the game reaches 700MB!

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage? Are you doing GC's before checking?

Comment: I look at the memory value in my android phone under active apps

Comment: You should do a GC before drawing any conclusions about memory usage as the heap will likely have dead objects in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have to manually call your Game class's dispose() method. It's called automatically upon changing screens or closing the app. Instead, you should override the Game dispose() like this (code taken from a project I'm working on):

```
@Override
public void dispose()
{
   super.dispose();
   assets.dispose();
}
```

The assets object is my AssetManager. Upon closing the app, I want all my loaded textures to be destroyed from memory. I can't promise anything, but I'm pretty sure that's your problem.